# How to create a custom class to add shadow to UINavigationBar IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, shadow

I need to make a custom class with the following code to set shadow to UINavigationBar in iOS.

```
@interface UINavigationBar (CustomImage)

-(void) applyDefaultStyle;

@end
@implementation UINavigationBar (DropShadow)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"titleBar.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
}

-(void)willMoveToWindow:(UIWindow *)newWindow{
    [super willMoveToWindow:newWindow];
    [self applyDefaultStyle];
}

- (void)applyDefaultStyle {
    // add the drop shadow
    self.layer.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 3);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}@end
```

How can I do that?

Also, the above code adds shadow to each and every navigationbar in my app. How to control this? I need shadow only on one or two navigationBars.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that every `UINavigationBar` is affected is because the code you have creates a [category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html) and modifies the existing class.

You would need to change the category to be a **subclass**:

```
@interface CustomNavigationBar : UINavigationBar
...
@end

@implementation CustomNavigationBar
...
@end
```

Then you can use the `UINavigationController` [`initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/initWithNavigationBarClass:toolbarClass:) and provide the `CustomNavigationBar` class on the navigation controllers you wish to affect:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithNavigationBarClass:[CustomNavigationBar class]
                                                                                      toolbarClass:nil];

// Make sure to provide a root view controller
[navController setViewControllers:@[rootViewController] animated:NO];
```

Answer (score 1):

You have implemented Category for UINavigationBar, Which will affect all UINavigationBar & It's Custom UINavigationBar(Subclass of UINavigationBar).

If you want this behaviour on only selected navigation bars, Then you can adopt the Inheritance(Subclass) of UINavigationBar.

[Take a look at this tutorial 1](http://just-works.blogspot.in/2013/11/subclass-category-and-extensions-in.html)

[Tutorial 2](http://blog.whitepeaksoftware.com/2010/09/11/customizing-the-look-of-uinavigationbar-and-uinavigationcontroller/)